# C++ - How would I insert values of my own type into a collection?

Tags: c++, collections, types, vector

I am writing a program which takes a name and number to create a student.
I then want to add these students to a collection.

However, what I am struggling with is how to add the students to the vector.

The code which I have written so far can be seen below:

```
Student stud(name, i);
vector<Student> vS

Student::Student(const string &name, int regNo) : Person(name)
{

}
```

I imagine there is something really stupid that I am doing but I really am very weak when it comes to programming.

I essentially am taking strings and integers from a file, these are then being passed to the Student constructor. I am then trying to create a Vector of type Student which includes all the students. But I just can't work out how to do this.

If anyone knows what I need to do then it would be great? I've tried a few methods but none of them seem to work.

Comment: How about `vS.push_back(stud)`?

Comment: Did you try using `push_back()` with your `std::vector<Student>` and a `Student` object? Also, you probably want to save the `regNo` in the constructor of your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert elements into `vector` `push_back` may be used:

```
vS.push_back(stud);
```

or if C++11 is available:

```
vS.emplace_back(name, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to look for is c++ documentation. There are also good examples there.
For example about vector:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
and about adding elements to the vector
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

As an additional comment, if you care about efficiency you may reserve space for elements:

```
your_vector.reserve(number_of_elements);
your_vector.push_back(your_element);
```